# How to still delete messages if a user edits them (python discord bot)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

So I‘ve got a python discord bot and it‘s made for deleting a users message if it contains some specific content. Here is a simplified version of the code:

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(ctx):
    if ctx.content == "some content":
        await ctx.delete()
    else:
        await bot.process_commands(ctx)
```

So now the problem is there are some smart guys now, who first send another message and then immediately edit it and write the content the bot should delete there. The problem is, the bot doesn‘t watch for edited messages. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check it with `on_message_edit` event.

```
@bot.event
async def on_message_edit(before, after):
    if after.content == "some content":
        await after.delete()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `discord.on_message_edit(before, after)` or `discord.on_raw_message_edit(payload)`. Heres the official API reference for them and how to use it: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_message_edit